# Scala Future, onComplete JsonParseException

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I am new to Scala and having a hard time to handle Future.

I am calling a method which returns Future[Seq[String]]

```
    def getBookingIds(headers: Seq[(String, String)]): Future[Seq[String]] = {

    val responseF = legacyService.get(new URL(Settings.Legacy.getBookingURL), headers)

    responseF.map { response =>
        response.extract[Seq[String]]
    }
}
```

I am calling above method here and need to loop through this list and check if booking exist.

```
    def verifyUserBooking(bookingId: Int, headers: Seq[(String, String)]): Unit = {

    bookedCruisesService.getBookingIds(headers).onComplete {
        case Success(s) => println()
        case Failure(ex) => println(ex.toString)
        case _ => println("what the hell happened")
    }
```

I am getting here JsonParseException. Why?

I have used different methods to loop through future list, but I keep getting Future in debug more.

Can someone help me to solve this issue, please.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing that `response.extract[Seq[String]]` is the part where it tries to turn a JSON response into something else and where it is blowing up. I would be interested if you could put `println(response.body)` above that line, so we can ensure the JSON you're getting is actually valid json. You can also try `if (response.status == 200)` with Play's WSClient Json libraries to figure out if you're getting an error page by accident.

Comment: You're also probably missing these imports: https://github.com/playframework/play-ws#scala and you probably supposed to call `extract` on `response.body`, not the response object itself.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds obvious, but you are getting a JSON parsing error because Play can't parse the JSON to the type that you specify. It is nothing to do with how you are handling the `Future`, which looks OK.

The type for `extract` is `Seq[String]`, so to match this the JSON would have to be an array of strings, e.g. `["A", "B", "C"]`. Check that this is what that URL is returning by printing the `response` before extracting it inside the `map` call, or by running it under a debugger and inspecting the values.

Comment: This is what I am getting when I am using debug more:
Failure(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Failed to parse json from xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"><string>3236766</string></ArrayOfstring>"; line: 1, column: 174])

Comment: That debugging is after the parsing failure so it is too late. You need to look at the JSON returned by the URL before you `extract` it in the `map` call. Trying printing the `response` (though you may need to look a bit deeper to find the raw JSON).